# Reloading prices on product page when product option selected

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

On my product view page, I'm outputting the product price in a couple of places using the getPrice and getSpecialPrice methods.

Selecting a product option on a configurable product won't update these prices at the front end though, which saddens me.

Can anyone tell me how I do about making these values update when we select an option from the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you do two separate methods binding them to a checklist box, one with the product price only (so that if the user selects it, it displays the face value of the product price) and the other one with example *x10% so that when the person checks it the product price will be decreased by 10% and store the temp new value so that you don't have it hard-coded.

Hope you get what I mean, my English is not so good

Answer (score 0):

You should learn something about Servlets coupled with ajax.